# Find a line and read next line in Python

Tags: python, line

In Python, for example, I decoding a url and find a report like this:

```
<title>Canada Olympic Park</title>

<description>Open  / Past 48 Hours: 0cm / Primary:  / Base Depth: 85cm</description>

<title>Castle Mountain</title>

<description>Open  / Past 48 Hours: 1cm / Primary:  / Base Depth: 179cm</description>

<title>Lake Louise</title>

<description>Open  / Past 48 Hours: 2cm / Primary:  / Base Depth: 162cm</description>
```

How can I use find() to locate the place I interesting and read the next line for further programming?
Basically how to find a specific line and read the next line under the line I just found?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `xml.dom.minidom`

Assuming your xml data is in a file

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

xmldata = open("abc.txt", "r")

domdata = parse(xmldata)

def getDescriptionData(title):
    titledata = [x.toxml().lstrip('<title>').rstrip('</title>') for x in domdata.getElementsByTagName('title')]
    descriptiondata = [x.toxml().lstrip('<description>').rstrip('</description>') for x in domdata.getElementsByTagName('description')]

    l =  [v for (x, v) in zip(titledata, descriptiondata) if x == title]
    if l:
        return l[0]
    return None

print getDescriptionData('Lake Louis')
```

Output:

```
Open  / Past 48 Hours: 2cm / Primary:  / Base Depth: 162cm
```

You can also look into [SAX XML parsing](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Sax)

Answer (score 1):

Try using itertools.dropwhile():

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep  4 2012, 20:19:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 20070831 patched [FreeBSD]] on freebsd9
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import itertools
>>> src="foo\nbar\nbas\n"
>>> notfoundyet=True
>>> def findthing(x):
...     global notfoundyet
...     currently=notfoundyet
...     notfoundyet=x!="bar"
...     return currently
... 
>>> itertools.dropwhile(findthing, src.split("\n"))
<itertools.dropwhile object at 0x8017d92d8>
>>> for x in _: 
...     print x
... 
bas
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getLine(source, string):
    source = source.split('\n')
    for index, item in enumerate(source):
        if string in item:
            return source[index + 1]
```